# Consulta na mesma tabela

Tags: sql, query, tabela-html

Tenho uma tabela movimento que tem o registro do trabalhador e os eventos a ele relacionado,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

queria um consulta que retornasse apenas os registros que possuem exatamente os eventos e1,e2 e e3, no caso do exemplo acima os registro seriam o 001 e 003

Comment: Utilize a cláusula WHERE. Um pequeno tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Entendo, mas no caso teria que mostrar os trabalhadores que possuem exatamente os três eventos apenas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não especificou qual base de dados está utilizando, mas pode fazer isso de várias maneiras. Usei o Mysql de exemplo e fiz 2 formas para isso:

> Usando [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
select distinct
m.registro
from movimento m
where 
exists (select 1 from movimento x where x.registro = m.registro and x.evento = 'e1')
and
exists (select 1 from movimento x where x.registro = m.registro and x.evento = 'e2')
and
exists (select 1 from movimento x where x.registro = m.registro and x.evento = 'e3');
```

> Resultado:

```
registro
001
003
```

---

> Usando [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) e [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select distinct
m.registro,
GROUP_CONCAT(m.evento) as eventos
from movimento m
group by m.registro
having 
INSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(m.evento),'e1') > 0
and 
INSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(m.evento),'e2') > 0
and 
INSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(m.evento),'e3') > 0;
```

> Resultado:

```
registro    eventos
001         e1,e2,e3
003         e1,e2,e3
```

Coloquei no **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d3e5/8)**

Comment: Funcionou amigo, obrigado

Comment: @NaalielCorrêa marque como resposta por favor. Se tiver dúvidas acesse o [Tour] para ver como

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma alternativa:

```
SELECT registro FROM trabalhador 
WHERE registro IN (SELECT registro FROM trabalhador WHERE evento = 'e1')
AND registro IN (SELECT registro FROM trabalhador WHERE evento = 'e2')
AND registro IN (SELECT registro FROM trabalhador WHERE evento = 'e3') 
GROUP BY registro
```

Abraço.

Comment: Também funcionou amigo, obrigado